# Microsoft Access - stored procedure with cursor

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that I am using to delete duplicates from one of the tables.

This stored procedure makes use of a cursor.

I tried to create the same stored procedure in Microsoft Access by just replacing the 'CREATE PROCEDURE' with 'CREATE PROC' but it didn't seem to work.

Can anyone provide some workaround?

Here is the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_loginfo_duplicates] 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


declare @minrowid bigint
declare @empid nvarchar(15)
declare @dtpunched datetime
declare @count tinyint

declare curDuplicate cursor for
    select empid,dtpunched,count(*),min(row_id) from loginfo
    group by empid,dtpunched
    having count(*)>1

open curDuplicate

fetch next from curduplicate into @empid,@dtpunched,@count,@minrowid

while (@@fetch_status=0)
    begin
        delete from loginfo where empid=@empid and dtpunched=@dtpunched and row_id<>@minrowid
        fetch next from curduplicate into @empid,@dtpunched,@count,@minrowid

    end
close curDuplicate
deallocate curDuplicate
END
```

Comment: Is removing the duplicates something you need to do one time only, or must it be a recurring task?

Comment: In access loginfo is a native table not a link. I dont need to remove duplicates regularly. Just once in a while. Right now I am looking into another project once I start working on this again, I will seek your advice. You have been very helpful. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with Jet 4 (Access 2000), Access DDL includes support for CREATE PROCEDURE when you execute the DDL statement from ADO.  However, those "procedures" are limited compared to what you may expect based on your SQL Server experience.  They can include only one SQL statement, and no procedural type code.  Basically an Access stored procedure is the same as a saved query, and is therefore subject to the same limitations which include the fact that Access' db engine doesn't speak T-SQL.

As for a workaround, you could create an Access-compatible DELETE statement to remove the duplicates. But I would first look for "the simplest thing which could possibly work".

1. Run your stored procedure on SQL Server to remove the duplicates.
2. Create a unique constraint to prevent new duplicates of the empid/dtpunched pairs in your loginfo table.
3. In your Access application, create a link to the SQL Server loginfo table.

However, I have no idea whether that suggestion is appropriate for your situation.  If you give us more information to work with, chances are you will get a better answer.

Comment: thank you hansup ! I am working on those lines moving data from access to sqlserver, running the storedprocedure then linking the sql table to access database